# Including first iteration in loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I wrote this program to give the user all acute triangle solutions when they give a min and max value. It works correctly except it seems like the solutions don't include the first iterations of the loops (for example, with min = 1 and max = 45, (1, 1, 1) isn't included in the solutions). How can this be fixed? I thought the problem was with my while-loop for the a-value, but when I changed it into a for-loop, the problem persisted. How can I have it include these first values?

```
if (c >= dmin) {
    c = dmin;
    do {
        ++c;
        for (b = dmin; b < dmax; b++) {
            a = dmin;
            while (a < dmax) {
                a = a + 1;
                if (a * a + b * b - c == c * c) {
                    if (((a + b) > c) && ((b + c) > a) && ((c + a) > b)) {
                        printf("(%d, %d, %d)", a, b, c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (c <= dmax);
}
```

Comment: In the inner loop, when `a` starts as `dmin` aka `1`, the first thing you do is increment it to `2`...so the version with `a == 1` is never tested.  You need to revise the logic.  Except perhaps as a learning exercise, using all three loop types nested is just a nightmare.  There should be three `for` loops for a sane solution.  Also using `c++` and `a = a + 1;` is rather inconsistent too.

Comment: I changed it to a++ right after I posted this. Also yeah I started with three `for` loops but unfortunately it's a learning exercise that requires all 3

Comment: As a learning exercise, I'd first write working code using `for` loops (only), then using `while` loops only, and then using `do … while` loops only.  Then I'd do a mix'n'match from the 3 working solutions.  It'd probably be quicker that way.  And I'd definitely start with the `for` loop solution; it is by far the cleanest with all the loop controls on a single line.

Comment: I think you mean isosceles triangles, not acute; as all triangles have at least 1 acute angle by design. If that is not the case can you provide the expected output for say: min=1, max=5?

Answer (score 5):

move `++c;` after the for loop instead of before.

This increments c to 2 before it even starts, but you want to include 1.

*Note, you may want to add conditions that prevent minimums of 0 or less.

Comment: I changed the a = a + 1 after I posted this, and earlier in the code (a part I didn't post) ensures that the values are both >0. But thank you for helping!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused, when I moved the `++c` to after the for loop, the program seems to have skipped the last two loops altogether and provides no output

Comment: You will also need to make your loops <= dmax, instead of just <

Answer (score 0):

If the value range for `a`, `b` and `c` is `[dmin..dmax]` (both inclusive), the sample looks like below:

```
for (c = dmin; c <= dmax; c++)
{
  for (b = dmin; b <= dmax; b++)
  {
    for (a = dmin; a <= dmax; ++a)
    {
      if (a * a + b * b - c == c * c )
      { 
        if (((a + b) > c) && ((b + c) > a) && ((c + a) > b)) 
        {
          printf("(%d, %d, %d)", a, b, c);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```